# Excel seizing up on large number of equations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset, ~400k lines and excepted to grow. I have a set of rules to determine duplicates - C&D&E&(condition)*F.

I then check for duplicates using =Countif(A$2:A$400000,A2), then a =if(Mod(B2,2)=0,"Duplicate","Not Duplicate")

However, my attempts to populate the formula down are proving problematic. Namely, excel seizes up and stops doing anything. No calculations displayed, not able to click or interface with it, heck, I don't even get a "not responding". I'm going to take a wild stab here and say it's due to the number of equations present.

What's a good method for checking for duplicates, and being successful?

Edit: Figured it out. Sort on the unique ID, then do a "local" countif - C10=Countifs(A1:A20,A10)

Comment: Spreadsheets were really never designed for that kind of workload; that's what databases are for.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. If you solved it, you are allowed to answer your own question below.